# angular2-material2 using ES6:

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

is there any way to start with angular2 material2 using ES6?

I have tried to find the way but Failed.

Also checked the git repo where found that all code exist for now with TS

so does it mean we can't able to use it with ES6

is there atlernative to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with Angular you can use vanilla JavaScript - either es5 or es6 - your choice. You can also use Typescript or Dart. Many of the tutorials you see use Typescript, because it works so well with Angular, and because the Angular team use it as their default. But you're certainly not tied to having to use that. If you prefer to use vanilla JS you certainly can -- because, remember, it all gets compiled down to JS, regardless of what you use for your coding.

Also, you can use Material2 regardless of what language and language version you're using to code with in your Angular app.

More info here: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html

And to use Material in your Angular app, see this: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: angular2 with es6 working for me..but i have not found any reference for material2..do have any idea or reference?

Comment: I added the link re: Material info above.

Comment: @Pankaj, did you see the Material link I provided above? If this was helpful, please mark it as correct.